# Swift - Store Closures in Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift, closures

Is it possible to store closures in dictionaries (how we could store ObjC blocks in dictionaries)?  Example:

```
   data = [String:AnyObject]()
   data!["so:c0.onSelection"] = {() in
       Debug.log(.Debug, message: "Hello, World!")
   }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can, but with some restrictions. First of all, function types don't inherit from AnyObject and don't share a common base class. You can have a dictionary `[String: () -> Void]` and `[String: (String) -> Int]`, but they can't be stored in the same dictionary.

I also had to use a typealias to define the dictionary so that swift would parse correctly. Here's an example based off of your snippet.

```
typealias myClosure = () -> Void
var data: [String: myClosure]? = [String: myClosure]()
data!["so:c0.onSelection"] = {() -> Void in
    Debug.log(.Debug, message: "Hello, World!")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a different approach

I create a "holder" class to hold your closures something like this:

```
typealias SocialDownloadImageClosure = (image : UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> ()
typealias SocialDownloadInformationClosure = (userInfo : NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()


private class ClosureHolder
{
 let imageClosure:SocialDownloadImageClosure?
 let infoClosure:SocialDownloadInformationClosure?

 init(infoClosure:SocialDownloadInformationClosure)
 {
    self.infoClosure = infoClosure
 }
 init(imageClosure:SocialDownloadImageClosure)
 {
    self.imageClosure = imageClosure
 }
}
```

then i make the dictionary like this:

```
var requests = Dictionary<String,ClosureHolder>()
```

Now to add a closure to the dictionary just do this:

```
self.requests["so:c0.onSelection"] = ClosureHolder(completionHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

Connor is correct, I did try many ways to store variables and closures in the same dictionary, but I failed and couldn't parse it out, the swift decompiler will throw the error:

```
"Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" (the hell is it?!)
```

For example:

```
//This won't work
var params:[String: Any] = ["x":100, "onFoundX": {println("I found X!")}]
if var onFoundX: (()->Void) = params["onFoundX"] as? (()->Void) {
    onFoundX()
}

//This should work by separate into 2 dictionaries and declare the "typealias" obviously
var params:[String: Any] = ["x":"100"}]
var events:[String: (()->Void)] = ["onFoundX": {println("I found X!")]

if var onFoundX: (()->Void) = events["onFoundX"] as? (()->Void) {
    onFoundX() // "I found X!"
}

if var x = events["x"] as? String {
    println(x) // 100
}
```

I hope Swift will allow this to happen in the future..

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This simple example helped me understand a bit more:

```
//Init dictionary with types (i.e. String type for key, Closure type for value):
var myDictionary: [String: ()->(String)] = [:]

//Make a closure that matches the closure signature above and assign to variable (i.e. no parameter and returns a String):
let sayHello: () -> (String) = {
    return "Hello!"
}

//Add closure to dictionary with key:
myDictionary["myFunc"] = sayHello

//Access closure by known key and call it:
myDictionary["myFunc"]!() //"Hello!"
```